# setting header for get erquest with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ws

I have the following curl request :

```
curl -k -X GET "URL?searchText=test" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-API-TOKEN: "Token"
```

and i want to consume this WS using Spring so i used the following piece of code:

```
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("X-API-TOKEN","Token");
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);
            ResponseEntity<String>response = 
            restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity,String.class);
```

But it doesn't seem to work and it shows this error:
[image]

Can anyone showm where i am supposed to do to fix that

Comment: a 404 means not found, so the URL you are using is wrong at first glance.

Comment: Are you trying to use a Bearer token `headers.setBearerAuth("Token");` to authenticate API requests ?